# SQL Server 2012, database [DBname] is not accessible

Tags: sql-server

When I log in with the Windows user all is okay, but when I log in with the SQL Server user, and then expand a database, I get a message:

> database [DBname] is not accessible

I've tried to set the permissions of the user, but after I click "ok", they reset to the default. What can I do to make the database accessible?

Comment: Try to open SQL management studio in admin mode and then to permission changes

Comment: Does the SQL Server user has privilege to access the DB? You could log on the windows user to open the DB and check it.

Comment: @wherby where can I see/change edit if I log with the windows user?

Comment: You could see the steps from the link to find the user infos :https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx

Comment: @user3112115 are you the db admin? your user (either the windows or the sql one) is allowed to grant permissions to other users?